# Difference between graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
def PlotPolly(model, independent_variable, dependent_variabble, Name):
    x_new = np.linspace(15, 55, 100) 
    y_new = model(x_new)

    plt.plot(independent_variable, dependent_variabble, '.', x_new, y_new, '-') #4
    plt.title('Polynomial Fit with Matplotlib for Price ~ Length')
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.set_facecolor((0.898, 0.898, 0.898))
    fig = plt.gcf()
    plt.xlabel(Name)
    plt.ylabel('Price of Cars')

    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

I get this with this code:

[image]

But when from line 4 I remove x_new and y_new line becomes

```
plt.plot(independent_variable, dependent_variabble)
```

I get this graph :

[image]

Can you explain what is meaning of x_new and y_new and why absence of this results in this kind of graph

Comment: What are these inverse quotes in the beginning of each line of your code? Please remove them!

Comment: @desertnaut I did that for identation because with tab didn't work.Is there any shortcut for identation?

Comment: As you should have already seen, the inverse quote will certainly not do the job.

Comment: @unit1991 I recommend that you indent the code in a text editor or application you are using before pasting it here. You can also put you code in the question, select it, and press the button with `{}` with braces. It will indent the code for you with 4 spaces. Or you can write triple-backtick before the first line of code and after the last. Read the formatting help. You can see the real-time result of the post you are writing under the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `x_new` and `y_new` both of them have the continuous values but `independent_variable` and `dependent_variabble` have ‍`discontinuous` values and for plot `discontinues` you need `scatter plot`. see this example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.array([2, 1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 6, 4])
y = np.array([3, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 6, 4])

plt.plot(x, y, linestyle='-', marker='o')
```

Output:

[image]